# Tabulator.prototype.findTable() returns an Array of length == 1

Tags: tabulator

Release notes say :

If no match is found it will return false, if one table is found it will return the Tabulator object for that table. If multiple tables are found it will return an array of all matching Tabulator objects.

tabulator.js :

```
return Array.isArray(results) && !results.length ? false : results;
```

which clearly doesn't check for results.length == 1

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has been updated.  It will return an array of matches.
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/options#find-table